# display a line every two line (osX) zsh

Tags: macos, unix, zsh

I'd to display every two line, a line from a file. I've seen the `sed -n 'f~d'` `awk` and `per`l  method. But the `sed` one doesn't work on osX (As I understood) and the two others are are interpreted languages which i can't use.

Can you help me ?

Here's an exemple :

output before :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  22 Jul 17 12:36 test.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test1.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  22 Jul 17 12:36 test2.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test3.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  22 Jul 17 12:36 test4.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test5.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  22 Jul 17 12:36 test6.sh
```

output after :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test1.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test3.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test3.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mfassi-f  2013  29 Jul 17 12:30 test5.sh
```

Comment: Do you have to use `ls -l`? Are these actually from a file, or are you piping `ls` output to the solution, ie `ls -l | sed ... `?

Comment: Yes, I have to use `ls -l` and I must pipe it.... :) as I have to give a `.sh` file containing a "supposed" easy command-based command line.

Comment: Your last comment may mean that the solution I've given [edited my answer] doesn't quite fit what you're after. Explaining exactly what you're after may be useful, although if it's a school project you may just want to use the answers here as inspiration for your own work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here are two answers. One for a file, and one for command-line input.

['cause the question's changed ever so slightly, but these two seemed too similar to put as independent answers].

You can use `zsh`, `ls`, `cut` and `paste` to do this in a for loop. It's not the cleanest solution, but it does work (surprisingly).

```
for file in `ls -1 | paste - - | cut -f 1`
do
   ls -l -d $file
done
```

We take the output of `ls -1`, then extract every second filename. (The way `ls` chooses to sort the files will have an impact here). Then, we do `ls -l -d` on each of these files. `-d` is necessary to stop `ls` from showing us the contents of `$file`, if `$file` is a directory. (Not sure if this is OS X specific, or if that's default POSIX ls behaviour).

---

#### Second answer: display every second line from a file.

If you're after a *mostly* `zsh` solution, you could do something like the following:

```
$ jot 8 0 7 >> sample.txt # Generate some numbers. 
$ count=0                 # Storage variable
$ for i in `cat sample.txt` 
do
if [ $(( $count % 2 )) -eq 0 ] ; then
echo $i
fi
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

This displays every second line.

**Notes:**
 - This leaves a variable `count` in your session afterwards (it's not clean).
 - This fails *badly* if `sample.txt` does not contain a single word per line.
 - I'm almost sure that the modulus comparison I do isn't the most efficient: I grabbed it from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/49765/how-to-make-a-statement-that-checks-if-something-is-divisible-by-something-else).
 - I say it's *mostly* zsh because it does rely on `cat`, but I'm not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: To avoid the `cat`, use `for i in $(< ~/filename); do`

Answer (score 0):

The OS X version of `sed` is frustrating. Using `sed -n '0~2p' <filename>` doesn't work because, in the BSD sed, `-n` does something different:

> -n
>   By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard output after all of the commands have been applied to it.  The -n option suppresses this behavior.

I'd highly recommend installing GNU sed, which can be done using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

And then you can use:

```
gsed -n '0~2p' filename # Display the 2nd, 4th etc
gsed -n '1~2p' filename # Display the 1st, 3rd etc.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use anything external... But thank you, I'll use it for my own work, as this one is for school.